# How do I sort points by their x and y coordinates so that they are ordered from top to bottom, left to right?

Tags: python, sorting, coordinates, qgis

I have a QGIS layer full of address points and would like to order them so that are sorted from top to bottom and left to right.

For example, if the numbers represented address points and their order:

```
1  2  3   4    5 6
7      8   9  10 11   
12  13       14  15
```

I can sort by x value and sort by y value, but I cannot figure out how to sort x then y so that it resembles the example above.

```
points_xy = {}

# get every address point as a point
for addr in repr_addresses.getFeatures():

    points_xy[addr.id()] = addr.geometry().asPoint()

# sort by the x value
points_x = {k:v for k,v in sorted(points_xy.items(), key=lambda item: item[1].x())}

# somehow sort the y values so that the largest y and smallest x value are paired etc.
```

a sample of **points_x** output looks like:

```
{106: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509838.75678090960718691 7411881.06174680404365063)>,
 117: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509843.64619539584964514 7411808.53339603915810585)>,
 19: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509855.7753696299623698 7411741.06764426827430725)>,
 23: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509856.84312249766662717 7411943.99649699591100216)>,
 97: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509878.72972580068744719 7411674.63795705512166023)>,
 125: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509885.47501007048413157 7412007.60445643309503794)>,
 119: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509901.95971070020459592 7411607.84251245018094778)>,
 126: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509930.84361596498638391 7411561.0557684525847435)>,
 100: <QgsPointXY: POINT(1509932.70123085496015847 7412072.57200376782566309)>,
```

Comment: Looks like you don't need to sort by second axis (let's say `y`) since it looks impossible to have same value in any given (let's say `x`) axis.

Answer (score 0):

> I can sort by x value and sort by y value

Just do exactly that (the latter sort with `reverse=True`).